# Does the as3lxs support all versions of excel (.xls, .xlsx, .csv)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, file-import, as3xls

Does the as3lxs support all versions of excel i.e, .xls, .xlsx & .csv .

Comment: a one second google search shows 1) it says  from Excel version 2.x-2003  2) the project was last updated in 2008... so my guess... don't count on it.  But give it a try... see what you get.

Comment: It doesn't support most of the char sets. (might be interesting fact)

Answer (score 1):

According to comments left on the  [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/as3xls/wiki/Tutorial) it not only doesn't support xlsx (which is XML based so you might find other tools for this) or CSV (which isn't an excel format but a much easier set of comma separated values which might not be hard to parse by hand) but it looks like it can't work with all flavors of xls. But perhaps it's better than nothing.

Comment: Is any other library is there which handle this case?

Comment: There are always server side approaches like Apache POI. I'm afraid the picking are slim on client side Excel parsing. Maybe look at this one: https://github.com/childoftv/as3-xlsx-reader

Comment: I am trying to parse all the above formats using a flex application in a single function

Comment: It looks like you will need to encorporate all three libraries to get that wide of support and be upfront on the limitations. It's a hard problem to solve.

Comment: yes, that's the last option to encorporate all three libraries and depending on file format choose the right one.